# What exit code does a Rust program return if main returns an Err

Tags: rust

In the current version of Rust (1.43) what exit code does a program produce if you return an `Err` from `main()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Termination](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/trait.Termination.html) trait is used to get an exit code from whatever `main` returns. The existing implementations wrap libc's `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `EXIT_FAILURE` which... are implementation-defined. But on unix-like systems they're probably `0` and `1`.

Comment: Ah I did find that but figured it wasn't available yet since `anyhow::Result` doesn't implement it. But seems like there is a default implementation which returns `EXIT_SUCCESS`/`EXIT_FAILURE`. Thanks!

Comment: @Timmmm there's an implenentation of Termination specifically for `Result<(), E>` and `Result<!, E>` in the stdlib. Since `anyhow::Result` is just a typedef for `Result<T, anyhow::Error>` it inherits these implementations as long as `T` is either `()` or `!`.